What happens with the water in a pipe when I quickly turn the tap
Assume I have a long pipe of diameter $D$ (e.g. 2cm) and length $L$ (e.g. 10m). The pipe is filled with water.
There is a tap at the start of the pipe, which regulates its flow rate.
I measure the flow rate at the end of the pipe.
Initially, water is flowing with a constant rate $F_1$ (e.g. 5 liters / minute).
I quickly turn the tap. Some time later, water is flowing with a constant rate $F_2$ (e.g. 10 liters / minute).
Questions:

What happened inside of the pipe? Is it correct to assume that there is a pressure gradient which travels inside of the pipe, such that, in front of this gradient, the rate is still $F_1$, but behind it, it is $F_2$.
How fast does this gradient travel? How much time will it take until the flow rate at the end of the pipe is $F_2$?
How long is the gradient? What is its shape? Is it a smooth transition, like a sigmoid, or are there wiggles?

Reason to ask the question: I'm interested in making a rough model of the heating system in a house to guesstimate how much heat goes where. I'm trying to assess which effects I can approximate, and which I really have to care about. Thus, I don't need an analytically super-accurate solution.

My guess would be that the pressure wave travels through the pipe at the speed of sound (since that's what they are!), and the shape of the wavefront would probably be determined by the tap's geometry

So, is it correct to assume that the wavefront is very narrow, and travels very fast? In other words, is it a good approximation that (on the scale of a single house) water flow speeds update instantly in the entire heating system? I presume the answer is yes, because the longest loop in a house is ~100m, which would take a fraction of a second to update with the speed of sound. For heating purposes, everything significantly faster than 1 minute is essentially instant.

Yes, I'd say it would be a fair assumption

You shoukld also keep in mind that water is (essentially) incompressible. Thus, the flow rate will be (very nearly) uniform along the length of the pipe. (This is what causes water hammers.)
